# Javascript stack traces are truncated

Tags: javascript, node.js, stack-trace

In both node and chrome, the following code only gives me 10 stack frames, when I would expect 100. Is there any way to get the whole stack printed?

```
function blowUp(n) {
    if(n > 100) { 
        throw new Error('x') 
    } else { 
        blowUp(n+1) 
    }
}

try {
    blowUp(0)
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e.stack)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign to the `stackTraceLimit` property of the `Error` constructor, which defaults to 10:

```js
function blowUp(n) {
    if(n > 100) { 
        throw new Error('x') 
    } else { 
        blowUp(n+1) 
    }
}

try {
    Error.stackTraceLimit = 20;
    blowUp(0)
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e.stack)
} finally {
    Error.stackTraceLimit = 10;
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Any idea why it's such a low limit? Performance? Memory?

Comment: Possibly, but also possibly because the source of the error is often not far removed from the frame that throws it. Maybe a programmer having to go through *more than 10* frames to find what they need to fix (or something that points to what they need to fix) is unlikely. Also, huge stack traces can make the output harder to read, when often only a few lines are needed. But that's just a guess.